# File check-out prompt for subversion in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

Is it possible to get a prompt when trying to check-out files from subversion using Eclipse? I have tried Subclipse and Subversive and am using [Assembla](https://www.assembla.com) as the host; could not find any setting that could give me this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no checkout possible (if you think from the perspective of a MKS or ClearCase user) or necessary (from the perspective of a Subversion user). The only way to achieve what you want to is to have the property needs-lock defined on the files  you want to haven an explicit "check-out" needed.

Do the following steps to prove it:

1. Add the svn-property svn:needs-lock to one file and commit this change.
2. Ensure that the lock is released in the commit.
3. Try to change that file now in Eclipse. The file should be read-only.
4. You are now able to use the "get lock" action, so the file changes after that to read-write

But be aware: This is not a useful usage of Subversion when working with sources. Subversion is an optimistic VC system (only), and everyone that tried to use it in a pessimistic way (need to do an explicit check-out) failed in using it.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that, with SVN, all files are directly read/write in your workspace: you don't signal to the CVCS (Centralized VCS which is SVN) that you are about to modify a file ("checkout").

You will get a prompt on the "checkin" phase, called commit.
This is an atomic operation, which will concern all modified/added/removed files within the current local workspace compared to the remote repo.